# Slow delete of object properties in JS in V8

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

Just to train myself a bit of Typescript I wrote a [simple ES6 Map+Set-like implementation based on plain JS Object](https://github.com/iskolbin/tsstringmap). It works only for primitive keys, so no buckets, no hash-codes, etc. The problem I encountered is implementing delete method. Using plain `delete` is just unacceptably slow. For large maps it's about 300-400x slower than ES6 Map delete. I noticed the huge performance degradation if size of the object is large. On Node JS 7.9.0 (and Chrome 57 for example) if object has 50855 properties `delete` performance is the same as ES6 Map. But for 50856 properties the ES6 Map is faster on 2 orders of magnitude. Here is the simple code to reproduce:

```js
// for node 6: 76300
// for node 7: 50855
const N0 = 50855;

function fast() {
 const N = N0

 const o = {}
 for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  o[i] = i
 }

 const t1 = Date.now()
 for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  delete o[i]
 }
 const t2 = Date.now()

 console.log( N / (t2 - t1) + ' KOP/S' )
}

function slow() {
 const N = N0 + 1 // adding just 1

 const o = {}
 for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  o[i] = i
 }

 const t1 = Date.now()
 for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
  delete o[i]
 }
 const t2 = Date.now()

 console.log( N / (t2 - t1) + ' KOP/S' )
}

fast()

slow()
```

I guess I could instead of `delete` properties just set them to `undefined` or some guard object, but this will mess the code, because `hasOwnProperty` will not work correctly, `for...in` loops will need additional check and so on. Are there more nice solutions?

P.S. I'm using node 7.9.0 on OSX Sierra

**Edited**
Thanks for comments guys, I fixed OP/S => KOP/S. I think I asked rather badly specified question, so I changed the title. After some investigation I found out that for example in Firefox there is no such problems -- deleting cost grows linearly. So it's problem of super smart V8. And I think it's just a bug:(

Comment: I see the same effect in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397034/why-is-delete-slow-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, `delete` is known to be slow

Comment: A different measurment tool: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1400/0/performance-of-delete-on-large-arrays

Comment: @Mike McCaughan thanks, looks amazing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) Yes, this is a known issue. The underlying problem is that objects should switch their elements backing store from a flat array to a dictionary when they become too sparse, and the way this has historically been implemented was for every `delete` operation to check if enough elements were still present for that transition *not* to happen yet. The bigger the array, the more time this check took. Under certain conditions (recently created objects below a certain size), the check was skipped -- the resulting impressive speedup is what you're observing in the `fast()` case.

I've taken this opportunity to fix the (frankly quite silly) behavior of the regular/slow path. It should be sufficient to check every now and then, not on every single `delete`. The fix will be in V8 6.0, which should be picked up by Node in a few months (I believe Node 8 is supposed to get it at some point).

That said, using `delete` causes various forms and magnitudes of slowdown in many situations, because it tends to make things more complicated, forcing the engine (*any* engine) to perform more checks and/or fall off various fast paths. It is generally recommended to avoid using `delete` whenever possible. Since you have ES6 maps/sets, use them! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I think this clarifies the whole thing:)

Comment: @jmrk Thanks for the response. Could you clarify you last comment on using maps/sets? I have a couple of objects that change all the time and the code uses delete. Would I be better using a Map and use the Map.delete(item)?

Comment: @leonormes: Yes, that's the recommendation. Using a `Map` tells the engine "I'm going to use this thing as a map, so don't even bother trying to detect what use case to optimize its internal representation for".

Comment: So is it what you are saying that we should avoid `delete` to save CPU resources? But don't we then lose memory resources? Or is it that the CPU savings are so great due to the certain internal engine's behavior in this particular case, that we should sacrifice memory instead. What about other, non-array cases, is it OK to use `delete` there to free memory? I will be very grateful for you answer.

Comment: `delete` is not guaranteed to free any memory. Using a `Map` instead of an `Object` or `Array` should generally not consume any more memory. That said it is always "OK" to use `delete`, it's just not efficient, so the recommendation is not to use it. Using `delete` on object properties tends to be particularly inefficient. What "non-array cases" do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question "why adding 1 to N slows the delete operation".

My guess: the slowness comes from the way the memory is allocated for your `Object`.

Try changing your code to this:

```
(() => {
    const N = 50855

    const o = {}
    for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        o[i] = i
    }

    // Show the heap memory allocated
    console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapTotal);
    const t1 = Date.now()
    for ( let i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        delete o[i]
    }
    const t2 = Date.now()

    console.log( N / (t2 - t1) + ' OP/S' )
})();
```

Now, when you run with `N = 50855` the memory allocated is: "8306688 bytes" (8.3MB)

When you run with `N = 50856` the memory allocated is: "8929280 bytes" (8.9MB).

So you got a **600kb** increase in the size of the memory allocated, only by adding one more key to your Object.

Now, I say I "guess" that this is where the slowness come from, but I think it makes sense for the delete function to be slower as the size of your Object increases.

If you try with `N = 70855` you would still have same **8.9MB** used. This is because usually memory allocators allocate memory in fixed "batches" while increasing the size of an Array/Object in order to reduce the number of memory allocations they do.

Now, same thing might happen with `delete` and the `GC`. The memory you *delete* has to be picked up by the GC, and if the Object size is larger the `GC` will be slower. Also the memory might be released if the number of keys goes under a specific number.

(You should read about memory allocation for dynamic arrays if you want to know more; there was a cool article on what increase rate you should use for memory allocation, I can't find it atm :( )

PS: `delete` is not "extremely slow", you just compute the op/s wrong. The time passed is in milliseconds, not in seconds so you have to multiply by `1000`.

Comment: Thanks, edited code snipplet OP/S => KOP/S. But this not that important. The x300-400 performance degradation is. I think the problem is just the bug in smart implementation of objects in V8. Or maybe V8 authors think instead of using objects as hashtables use ES6 Map already! It's 2K17:)