# How to remove specific errors in Angular Form Group

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently I'm trying to create a dynamic validation in Angular Forms and I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553544/how-can-i-manually-set-an-angular-form-field-as-invalid).

Adding the error to the field

```
this.form.get('field').setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
```

Removing the error to the field

```
this.form.get('field').setErrors(null);
```

My question is how can I remove a specific error in the field? Example I have multiple `setErrors` and I only want to remove the `invalid` error

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not, setError replace all the errors. You can always use `setErrors(Validators.required)` or to have an array of errors `[Validators.required,Validators.minLenght(3)]` and use `setErrors(errorsArray)` but I suppose it's not you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
this.form.get('field').setError({'invalid': null})
```

Comment: Hi Ana it does not work. The invalid error is set to null, but the field detect that their is an error. I want to remove only an specific error because when I use the `setError(null)` even the `required` validation is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and thought of two ways to do it:

#### 1. Using `delete`

```js
const control = this.form.get('field');
const error = 'invalid';

if (control.hasError(error)) {
  delete this.form.get('field').errors[error];
}
```

However, this may be [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594092/slow-delete-of-object-properties-in-js-in-v8).
You should also check that the error exists using `hasError` as the rest of your code may not work otherwise. I made this mistake and wasted hours trying to figure why my code wasn't working.

#### 2. Using `setErrors`

```js
const control = this.form.get('field');
const error = 'invalid';

{ [error]: _ignored, ...errors } = control.errors;
control.setErrors(Object.keys(errors).length ? errors : null);
```

Here I'm using ES6 destructuring assignment together with the spread syntax to get only the errors that the control should have.

**Important**:
When setting errors, make sure to check that `errors` isn't empty by checking `Object.keys(errors).length` is more than 0. An empty object looks like this: `{}`, and this may flag the field as erroneous since `{}` is coalesced into `true`.

The `{ [error]: _ignored, ...errors }` syntax is useful for when `error` is a variable. I found myself using this when passing `error` as a parameter to a function. If `'invalid'` isn't stored in a variable, you can use this instead:

```
{ invalid: _ignored, ...errors } = control.errors;
```

Comment: When I try this using the destructuring assignment and spread operator, I get an error `Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'ValidationErrors | null'`.  Do you have any idea how to solve this?